# What's the expected resource loading priority when Jetty's setExtraClasspath is used?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, war

Is it expected that resources in .jar files included via Jetty's WebAppContext.setExtraClasspath method would be loaded in preference to resources with the same name/path within the .war?

——

I’m in the process of moving some dependencies out of .war files and including them instead via WebAppContext’s setExtraClasspath method (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html#using-extra-classpath-method)

While doing so, I ran into a problem where one of the .jar files now moved out contains an ehcache.xml file, which seems to be read in preference to the one within the .war when `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(“ehcache.xml”)` is used.

Now that I know that to be the case, I guess it’s not a big inconvenience to me if I need to rename the file to be unique, but I guess I’m wondering…

- Am I loading the resource incorrectly (and if so, how can I do it to the .war takes priority)?
- Was it only luck that the .war version took precedence previously (when the .jar in question was packed within the .war)?
- Is this an expected drawback of using setExtraClasspath that I just have to live with?
- Did I miss some documentation somewhere which would have clarified this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jan on the jetty-user's list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07738.html)...

> AFAIK we don't do any special handling of the extra classpath.  The order
>   of paths that are added to the URLClassLoader that is the webapp
>   classloader is:
>
> - extra classpath
> - WEB-INF/classes
> - WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
>
> The webapp classloader getResource(String) method first looks in itself
>   before looking in the parent (to conform to servlet spec inverted
>   classloading requirements), however the looking is all delegated to the
>   URLClassLoader, so it is whatever ordering the jvm has implemented, which
>   according to GrepCode
>   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#URLClassPath.0urls
>   looks like the search order will be as above.

Sad for my case, but makes sense.